# Slice preallocation slow than make

Tags: go, slice

Extracted from: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Performance

> A special case of allocation combining is slice array preallocation.
>   If you know a typical size of the slice, you can preallocate a backing
>   array for it as follows:
>
> ```
> type X struct {
>     buf      []byte
>     bufArray [16]byte // Buf usually does not grow beyond 16 bytes. }
>
> func MakeX() *X {
>     x := &X{}
>     // Preinitialize buf with the backing array.
>     x.buf = x.bufArray[:0]
>     return x }
> ```

Testing the difference:

```
package main

import "testing"

type buf struct {
        b []byte
}
type buf2 struct {
        b  []byte
        bt [2]byte
}

func B() *buf2 {
        b := &buf2{}
        b.b = b.bt[:0]
        return b
}

func BenchmarkMake(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                b := &buf{}
                b.b = make([]byte, 2, 2)
        }
}

func BenchmarkPreallocation(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                b := B()
                _ = b
        }
}
```

Output:

```
[user@SYSTEM temp]$ go test -bench . -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: temp
BenchmarkMake-8                 100000000               12.7 ns/op             2 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkPreallocation-8        50000000                40.4 ns/op            32 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Why preallocation is slow?

Why does the slice internals (pointing operation) `[:0]` use 32 bytes to do that?

Comment: Comparing microbenchmarks of different things is not very easy, and without a use-case, not very useful. Pre-allocation isn't slower, but `buf2` is larger than `buf` so it should allocate more. `buf2` slice also escapes to the heap, so it's not immediately reused and you allocate the entire thing every time.

Comment: Why is there a `makefile` tag on this question?

Comment: Which is better for hadleClient function that is running as goroutine? (to handle tcp clients). I'm reusing object instances with a channel and select.

Comment: @MadScientist stackoverflow changes automattically from make to makefile

Comment: @VasileM: neither is better, this is an attempt at optimizing a problem you don't have. Just use a slice, as pre-allocating for your slice generally doesn't do anything you can't do with `make`.

Comment: @JimB: okay. Thank you. My intention was to have 100 instances of the reusable object and the others (1000, 2000, etc) that are created in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: If you want to test pre-allocation, you need to do it with your real use case. Guessing how the code will be optimized by the compiler, especially before you write it, isn't going to help.

Comment: Not to mention, if you're creating a pool of 100 of these ahead of time, the time it takes to allocate means nothing to your program. Also, look at `sync.Pool` as an efficient way to re-using objects.

Comment: Okay. But it is complicated to perform bencharks or profiles of a server listening. I did it before, I have a client package to benchmark. In those things sometimes I prefer to write code according to the theory and not perform more tests for lack of time.

Comment: No, sync.Pool can lose the instances. Garbage Collector clean it.

Comment: This realy sound like premature optimisation. Stop that.

Comment: @Volker: If there are several ways to do the same, why not worry and always choose the most efficient?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: You must be joking. "The most efficient" is not something well defined and if it is well defined: Most of the time it simply does not matter. Strangely enough this pathological focus on irrelevant details is not considered insane by lots of programmers.

Comment: Nice philosophical approach but it's not my interest.  Many of the so-called programmers only care about comfort, simplicity and compatibility. Typical features of the methodology of Google.  Use the wheel, do not reinvent it. Because the wheel has a fork, microphone, flashlight, etc. and it will serve you. But nobody cares about the garbage code as a consequence of the design patterns, for example. Or the resources. Read the Stackoverflow, the good answer is the first because it works, but it is not the most efficient. This code is part of the production software.

Comment: Another example would be the design principles in Java. Invoking an interface method is expensive, but I have seen them in loops. Who cares about wasted processor clock cycles? The important thing is that the algorithm is effective in order to develop a lot of software and sell it in kilograms.